# Is There any Disadvantages for Using JQuery Load Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I am currently developing a web site which basiclly shows the sensor datas. The site must have a chart and I suppose to use HighChart line chart. Because of the website hasn't too much contents, I decided to make all the action one page (graphs, tables...). So this page has lots of parts. To avoid this clutter, I want to build graph part in another HTML file and via JQuery load function, use this in the main page. The only way that I know how to show or use the other codes is this.

For example:

```
$('.sampleDiv').load('sampleHtmlFile');
```

And the problem begins. I am not sure whether this way influence the whole page and its well designed structure. Is it bad practice for a developer? Are there any reason to or not to use load function like this way? Maybe another way to handle this problem...

By the way, I am too new for Web Development.

Comment: concept is fine. What you are describing is  *"Single Page Application (SPA)"* SEO and bookmarking abilities  though need to be considered

Comment: If the pages are not too big, the reformat of the DOM should be ok. SEO is indeed an issue. You can have links to your content in hidden divs for google to follow

Comment: It is actually local project. So in this case, SEO is not too important. Am I right?

Comment: SEO in this context just refers to search engine indexing. So if it is a tool only you are using then yes that would be correct

Comment: So I can use this way with peace of mind right?

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to use jQuery's `load` to load web-pages that depend on `javascript` (I assume you want to use http://www.highcharts.com/).
specially as a beginner you will run into a lot problems doing this.

**more info:**
`.load()` is nothing else than an ajax call - and you run into problems loading new `javascript` scripts to the page via ajax.
the browser can't handle loading scripts via ajax by itself correctly so the browser handles the request like it was synchronous and you'll receive this warning:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

to prevent this you'll need something like `jQuery.getScript()` to load external javascript files with `.load()`.

**TL;DR:**
I wouldn't recommend to load html files which include external javascript files when you are a beginner. you can get get into a lot of troubles - from missing dependencies into browsers handling the ajax requests like synchronous requests.

Comment: So If I apply this way properly, it is okey. But the problem is that can I handle this because of I am beginner... Right?

Comment: @kimdirbilmem well, I think you just have to include every external javascript file which you need in your html you load with `.load()` with `$.getScript()`. then you should be fine for the most part.

Comment: @kimdirbilmem you are welcome! if you run into other problems just post a new question.